# Jquery slider effect -- like a "reveal"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

Not sure what to call this effect and googling in linguistic darkness didn't help at all :)

This is the effect I am looking to get: 
http://www.studiobreakfast.be/

Any pointers or suggestions of keywords to look for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using [jQuery Nivo Slider v2.0](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Comment: Thanks Tx3, that's what I was after. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted uses [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/), which is a jQuery plugin with multiple image transitions.

Comment: Thanks Oiva. Tx3's answer comes before. I wish I could "accept" two answers, but I cannot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching for '[jQuery blinds transition](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery+blinds+transition+effect&pbx=1&oq=jquery+blinds+transition+effect&aq=f&aqi=q-w1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=10304l11352l2l11466l7l7l0l0l0l1l488l1365l0.5.1.0.1l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7a4c02153ade1456&biw=1280&bih=803)'?

That led me to this site among others: http://www.rdeeson.com/weblog/111/jquery-venetian-blinds-transition-effect.htm